# FFMPEG raises exception only when writing to pipe

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am currently writing a small application in Python that gets audio from a Youtube Link and converts this into wave data for visualization. I am using Pafy to get the appropriate URL, ffmpeg-python for the conversion, and matplotlib for visualization.

Currently, I am trying to skip the step of downloading the file to a local directory and instead want to write it directly into ffmpeg's pipe, so I can process it directly.

The function is the following:

```
import pafy
import os
import ffmpeg
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import wave

def getaudio(url, filename='temp.wav'):
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        os.remove(filename)
    source = pafy.new(url).getbestaudio(preftype='m4a').url
    try:
        out, _ = (
            ffmpeg.input(source)
            .output(filename, format='wav')
            .run(capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
        )
    except ffmpeg._run.Error as e:
        print(e.stderr.decode('utf-8'))
        raise e
    w = wave.open('temp.wav', 'r').readframes(-1)
    audio = np.frombuffer(w, dtype=np.int16)
    return audio


url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhZs3ALdL7Y'
audio = getaudio(url)
plt.plot(audio)
plt.show()
```

This works in general - however this does two things: It returns the audio so it can be opened with the wave package, and it also saves it as 'temp.wav' to the current directory, which I would like to skip by replacing the 'temp.wav' output with 'pipe:':

```
    try:
        out, _ = (
            ffmpeg.input(source)
            .output('pipe:', format='wav')
            .run(capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
        )
    except ffmpeg._run.Error as e:
        print(e.stderr.decode('utf-8'))
        raise e
```

This raises an exception with the following output for stderr:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid 
--enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://r4---sn-h0jelne7.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1610319670&ei=1jL7X_uZIoeC6dsP9Z6nsA8&ip=2a02%3A810d%3Aabbf%3Abeed%3A98a1%3Ae204%3A805c%3Aa5b1&id=o-AGmTIS4LdQhQz5h7nplFZ0h5iWHR3KxieH44x8mIvXab&itag=140&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=dj&mm=31%2C26&mn=sn-h0jelne7%2Csn-4g5e6nzz&ms=au%2Conr&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=33&initcwndbps=1885000&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fmp4&ns=qyAm3FG5c0DyOAH11rcQFxYF&gir=yes&clen=55649&dur=3.459&lmt=1508976590967371&mt=1610297792&fvip=4&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&n=YvU_SOWuTrPG1W&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRAIgLR-oEO3oWoBfBGslerzo-jO57JhY-xbfKxQJ1GcnpscCIAhuoixcr1X_uDGiUuJ5IbPD2zynF-R8Qp5BjQqSWUaF&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRgIhAO9pxuDZZeOd6pESsk4tjlpzDJeCnSqPv4G1-zJKoDI1AiEAjjwkSBZeeEivgAU_DRdnI-GokWQ3P-6gKhdGHe9Za7o%3D&ratebypass=yes':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6mp41
    creation_time   : 2017-10-26T00:09:50.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:03.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-10-26T00:09:50.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, wav, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6mp41
    ISFT            : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-10-26T00:09:50.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 pcm_s16le
size=     596kB time=00:00:03.45 bitrate=1411.4kbits/s speed= 316x
video:0kB audio:596kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.012781%

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/Coding Projects/YTStream/Test2.py", line 27, in <module>
    audio = getaudio(url)
  File "e:/Coding Projects/YTStream/Test2.py", line 20, in getaudio
    raise e
  File "e:/Coding Projects/YTStream/Test2.py", line 16, in getaudio
    .run(capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 325, in run
    raise Error('ffmpeg', out, err)
ffmpeg._run.Error: ffmpeg error (see stderr output for detail)
```

I am confused how to deal with this exception as there is no obvious error message here (at least to me).  It simply stops, as opposed to when I give an obvious error (such as an invalid format that is not supported by ffmpeg -formats).
Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: the ffmpeg log shows no errors - the output appears to be fully generated.

Comment: That's the weird part - I cannot find anything wrong with the output either, but still the writing to pipe: does not work as ffmpeg raises the above exception. I'm forced to make a copy on disk, which shouldn't happen. Very puzzling.

Comment: I don't see ffmpeg raising any exception.

Comment: It is in the very last line of the error log, which is what Python outputs to me: 'ffmpeg._run.Error: ffmpeg error (see stderr output for detail)', and the code stops running after the ffmpeg.run() command. The error log is already printed above because I included outputting stderr to console in the code. Of course you are correct - I do not see any clear error message in the log either, which is exactly what is confusing to me, but as the code stops running, out is not written either, and I cannot continue even if I ignore the ffmpeg exception.

Comment: That last line is from Python, not ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by working with FFMPEG directly instead of using the ffmpeg-python library. I am still unsure what exactly caused the error, but as Python, Pafy, FFMPEG and the source url all work, I'll assume that there is a bug in the library.
See here the updated code:

```
import pafy
import os
import subprocess as sp
import io
import wave
import numpy as np

def getaudio(url):
    source = pafy.new(url).getbestaudio()
    command = (
        ['ffmpeg.exe',
        '-i', source.url,
        '-f', 'wav',
        '-']
    )
    proc = sp.Open(command, stdout=sp.PIPE)
    out = proc.stdout.read()
    w = wave.open(io.BytesIO(out))  # Converts bytes-stream to file-like
    audio = np.frombuffer(w.readframes(w.getnframes()), dtype=np.in16)
    return audio
```